# I am working with quickblox webrtc video calling process

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working with quickblox webrtc video calling process. I am stuck on when someone receives my call and I am not getting response when the user accepts my call.

This is the method.

This method not call and I am not getting that he pick my call.

```
-(void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session userDoesNotRespond:(NSNumber *)userID {
    if (session == self.session) {
        [self performUpdateUserID:userID block:^(OpponentCollectionViewCell *cell) {
            cell.connectionState = [self.session connectionStateForUser:userID];
        }];
    }
}
```